# Xpath: How to find an element meeting certain criteria that comes before another element

Tags: xslt, xpath

**Task:**

With the context node being any of the `<pic>` elements (my processing is within
a `match="pic"` template), how do I return the first `<a>` element that meets both of the following criteria?

- Comes before the next `<pic>` element, AND
- Contains the string 'blah'

**Assumptions:**

1. `<pic>` elements are sometimes siblings of other `<pic>` elements, but
   not always.  Nor are they always siblings of other `<a>` elements.
2. `<a>` elements are sometimes siblings of other `<a>` elements, but not always.

Here's the XML structure:

```
<document>
<pic>
   <img>
</pic>
....
<ul>
   <li>       
      <pic>
         <img>
      </pic>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="someFile.html"> <!-- doesn't meet both criteria -->
   </li>       
</ul>
<p>
   <a href="anotherFile.html"> <!-- doesn't meet both criteria -->
<pic>
   <img>
</pic>
...
<a href="...blah....html"> <!-- meets both criteria -->
<pic>
   <img>
</pic>
...
<p>
   <a href="someOtherFile.html> <!-- doesn't meet both criteria -->
<p>
...
<pic>
   <img>
</pic>
...
<a href="...blah....html"> <!-- meets both criteria -->
...
<pic>
   <img>
</pic>
...
```

Comment: Is this XML or HTML ? You say XML, but I don't see any closing tags to match the <p>, which makes me think it's HTML. It's significant because if its HTML, you need to check whether the HTML parser makes the <a> a child or a sibling of the <p>.

Comment: XML.  I ommitted some closing tags b/c for brevity, and I felt I had to include several examples of where the elements could be.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

My Xml

```
<document>
    <pic title="match none"/>
    <ul/>
    <pic title="match one"/>
    <a title="one">blah</a>
    <pic title="match two"/>
    <a title="two">blah</a>
    <pic title="match none"/>
    <pic title="match three"/>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a title="three">blah</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <a title="none">blah,</a>
</document>
```

My XSL

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="pic">
        <!-- current pic identity -->
        <xsl:variable name="identity" select="generate-id()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="next-a-element" select="following::a[generate-id(preceding::pic[1]) = $identity][contains(.,'blah')]"/>

        <xsl:if test="$next-a-element">
            <xsl:comment>pic <xsl:value-of select="@title"/></xsl:comment>
            <xsl:comment>a: <xsl:value-of select="@title"/></xsl:comment>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My Result

```
<!--pic match one--><!--a: match one-->

<!--pic match two--><!--a: match two-->

<!--pic match three--><!--a: match three-->
```

Comment: Given the rewritten XML and a confusing question ... this is the answer I would have given

Comment: Wonderful!  Thank you.  My code situation shifted a bit (thus the delay in response) but this did work for me.  The clever use of the generate-id() to match up the elements did the trick.